# How to make Jarallax MDB work?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, parallax, mdbootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="view jarallax" data-jarallax = '{"speed":0.2 }' style="background- 
image: url('OFP/OFP_Group.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background- 
size: cover; background-position: center center;">
<div class="mask flex-center rgba-black-light"></div>
</div>
```

And for some reason, I cannot make it work as shown in the MDB example (https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/html/parallax/index.html). The image doesn't show up at all, if I add the width to the style, it shows the image, however the image doesn't have the jarallax effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems the problem was in my own ignorance. There is a snippet of CSS code in the [Parallax Intro section](https://mdbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap-parallax/). Put that in your blank style.css file and it should work fine. Below is the code you should put in your CSS file

```
/* Required for full background image */

html,
body,
header,
.jarallax {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
  html,
  body,
  header,
  .jarallax {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.top-nav-collapse {
  background-color: #82b1ff !important;
}

.navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
  background: transparent !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background: #82b1ff !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background: #82b1ff !important;
  }
}

h5 {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```